# Url Rewrite 404 Error Multistore view

Tags: url, url-rewrite, category-tree

I have two views english store and german. The switch for switching the two languages ​​works without problems. I find myself as on the German side imprint. From there I would like to switch to the English site. Instead of seeing the English imprint, I get an error 404 Page not found. I was able to solve the problem as follows.

```
Impressum = german site, english Site not active.

Page title: impressum
URL Key: impressum
Store view: deutsch
Status: active

And the english page as follows

imprint = englisch Site, german Site not active
Page title: imprint
URL Key: imprint
Store view: englisch
Status: aktiviert

German Site
Type: User configurated
Store. Deutsch
ID Path: impressum
Request Path: imprint
Target Path: impressum
Redirect: permanent


English Site
Type: User configurated
Store: Englisch
ID Path: imprint
Request Path: impressum
Target Path: imprint
Redirect: permanent


Now I wanted to do the same for each category . Unfortunately without success
Under Rewrite Url i have the following:

German Categorie
Type: User configurated
ID Path: category/3
Requet Path: bleistift
Target Path: catalog/category/view/id/3
Redirect: permanent

English Categorie
Type: Benutzerdefiniert
ID Path: category/4
Request Path: pencil
Target Path: catalog/category/view/id/4
Redirect: permanent
```

What is wrong?